# Automatic Browser Interoperability Tester by looking at Code

Tags: cross-browser, interop, browser

Assuming I already have valid code, is there a tool or plugin that I can use to evaluate my website code and highlight areas where different browsers could potentially display the code differently? I am aware of websites like [browsershots](http://browsershots.org/) and I have VMs to test, but I'm wondering if there is something to shortcut the process by looking at the code and warning of well known cross-browser compatibility red flags.

For example, when using CSS which is not universally supported yet. The following is valid CSS 2.1:

```
display: run-in;
```

Validators which are aware of CSS 2.1 will pass it with flying colors, but really, a red flag should be thrown, indicating that it does not work in Firefox 3. On the other hand,

```
border-radius: 10px;
```

is actually pretty well supported in updated browsers, even though it is CSS3.

This is new in Javascript, but is also passed by validators:

```
getElementsByClassName();
```

but it would be better if a warning popped up notifying me it won't work in IE8.

Another example is well known rendering bugs, which can be triggered by weird (valid) situations. I understand there is no replacement for opening up the website in every single browser on every system to really see how it works, but I am just wondering if there is some tool that can help check that I'm writing interoperable code as I go, so that I can test more frequently in the development process and spend less time working out bugs later.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer is no.

I once started looking into creating a tool exactly as you describe. The reality is that most libraries like jQuery actually **make use** of browser incompatibilities and different interpretations of standards (or ignoring the standards).

So, if you're using any of the standard libraries then you'd receive tons of warnings and actually get very little out of it. The amount of spam simply will shadow the actual bug you might have introduced.

What matters more is whether the incompatibilty actually affects the end result. Hence we went for what-you-see-is-what-you-test method instead of static code analysis.

Comment: Everything but your first sentence just reads like an advertisement for your service, again.

Comment: Andrew, I need to show the reference of my experience somehow?

Comment: No, you do not - and *especially* not by plugging your company/product, *yet again*. It looks like you are just trying to skirt the spamming rules.

Comment: Andrew, I took the reference to the product out. Hope it makes you happy.